# Eclipse PDE Popup Extensions for CDT

Tags: eclipse-pde

I just moved my plugin from Version 3.3.2 of Eclipse to Version 3.4.1. The popup menu extensions I added to the project navigator (via Object Contribution IFile) do not appear for C++ executables. IResource object Contributions to not appear on the Debug and Release folders. Have contributions been disabled for these types? Is there someway to extend the context menu on these objects?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue of different versions of Eclipse, but rather different Eclipse perspectives.

When the Project Navigator is opened in a C++ perspective, the objects representing the project, release/debug containers, and binary are not derived from IResource / IFile so the Object Contribution IFile cannot be used. These objects are in the 'CDT' package hierarchy.

In other perspectives, such as the PDE perspective, the objects in the tree do derive from IResource.